# 0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #<%=fieldGenieConnectionString.ClientID%>

Tags: javascript, ajax

Please see the code below:

```
function GroupUSNChange() {
        //$.ajax({
        //    type: "POST",
        //    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        //    dataType: "html",
        //    success: function OnSuccess(response) {
        var frm = document.forms[0];
        var usn = document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hfUSN");


        if (checkboxticked())
        {
            for (i = 0; i < frm.elements.length; i++) {
                if (frm.elements[i].type == "checkbox" && frm.elements[i].name.substr(0, 38) == "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$RematchGroup") {
                    if (frm.elements[i].checked == true) {
                        var id = frm.elements[i].name.split("|");
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "frmPNList.aspx/ChangeGroupOfUSNs",
                            async: false,
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            data: '{strNewUSN: "' + usn.value + '", strURNs: "' + id[1] + '", strDatasetName: "' + id[2] + '", strCon: "' + $("#<%=fieldGenieConnectionString.ClientID%>")[0].value + '"}',
                        //data: '{strNewUSN: 9, strURNs: 1, strDatasetName: 2}',
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: OnSuccess(),
                        error: function (xhr, errorType, exception) {
                            var errorMessage = exception || xhr.statusText; //If exception null, then default to xhr.statusText  
                            alert("there was an error changing the USN of the group: " + errorMessage);
                        },
                        failure: function () {
                            alert('there was an error changing the USN of the group.')

                        }
                    });

                    function OnSuccess() {
                        return function () {

                        }
                    }
                    //end of AJAX call
                }
            }
        }
        alert('Successfully changed the USN of the group')
            //},


            //error: function (xhr, errorType, exception) {
            //    var errorMessage = exception || xhr.statusText; //If exception null, then default to xhr.statusText  
            //    alert("there was an error creating a screenshot (part one): " + errorMessage);
            //},
            //failure: function (reponse) {
            //    alert('there was a problem creating a screenshot.')

            //}
            //});
        }
        else
        {
            alert("You must tick at least one tickbox"); 
        }


    }
```

The code works when I include it in the .aspx file.  However, when I create a .js file and reference the .js file; I am prompted with the following  error:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're putting ASP.NET (or some other server side code) in your JS.

If your JS is in a file that the server is processing as ASP.NET, then that's fine (so long as the data is properly escaped or contains no special characters).

When you put it in a static JS file, the server no longer processes it as ASP.NET and sends the code to the client … where it tries to execute it as JS and fails.

---

Either:

- Store the data in your HTML and read it from the DOM
- Generate your JS file from ASP.NET (making sure you set the Content-Type response header correctly).